# My light fixture made in China says use only 60volt 60W AC bulbs

Tags: light-fixture

What does the voltage of the fixture mean?  Can I put a 120V 60 watt equivalent LCD  bulb in it?  The fixture has a label saying only use 60 volt 60 watt ac bulb.  This is a new fixture I had put in a couple years ago by two electricians.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are you sure this says 60V 60W AC? That seems unlikely. Would you edit in a picture of the fixture and its label to your question?

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the fixture? And do you mean a LED bulb?

Comment: Lost in translation more than likely, probably translation that is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

#### Ain't no 60V around here...

If the instructions actually say **60V** then throw the whole thing away. Seriously. I don't know any place on a 60V system, and you mentioned 120V (normal for USA/Canada/etc.) anyway. So if it really says 60V then that is a sign of extremely poor quality and I would not trust the actual parts that matter to be any good.

#### If it really says 120V 60W

If it really says **120V** 60W, then this is an indication, often quite reasonable, that the fixture is not rated to dissipate more heat than generated by a 60W bulb. If that is the case, then you can normally put in any type of bulb - e.g., CFL, LED, a 40W incandescent, etc. - as long as it uses <= 60W of power. However, there are a few situations where straight replacement might not work:

- Dimmers - if the fixture or an attached switch provides dimming capability, that may not work properly with a CFL or LED bulb.
- "Smart" functions without a neutral - timing, remotes or other "smart" functions can either get a little bit of power through the bulb while it is "off", or they can be powered via the neutral. This trick of getting power through the bulb even when "off" doesn't work so well with CFL and especially LED bulbs.